# get position of duplicate values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have pandas dataframe 20,000 X 48 as below(not all data given).

```
     0       1       2       3       4
0    1  0.4784  0.4764  0.4251  0.4915
1    2  0.6180  0.4503  0.3737  0.5377
2    3  0.6735  0.4317  0.6295  0.5470
3    4  0.5294  0.5871  0.5278  0.5544
4    5  0.5555  0.4784  0.5443  0.5259
5    6  0.4784  0.5798  0.6118  0.5491
6    7  0.5397  0.8885  0.6683  0.6056
7    8  0.8174  0.7972  0.5230  0.5707
8    9  0.5763  0.6118  0.6675  0.5457
9   10  0.8045  0.6249  0.5407  0.6716
10  11  0.8036  0.6599  0.4947  0.6440
11  12  0.7665  0.5408  0.4784  0.6212
12  13  0.6273  0.7438  0.4784  0.8148
13  14  0.4217  0.8473  0.6894  0.7844
14  15  0.8768  0.4784  0.8009  0.5160
15  16  0.5410  0.9091  0.6329  0.7311
16  17  0.4784  0.5506  0.5655  1.0636
17  18  0.6490  0.5864  0.5687  1.2680
18  19  0.5173  0.4768  1.1053  0.5361
19  20  0.5841  1.0596  0.7043  0.6657
```

I want to get unique values from each column(0 to 4) and get at what position they occur.

example for column 1 I want to know the possition of each values as shown below

`[0.4784:(0,16), 0.6180:1, 0.6735:2...... so on]`

is there any inbuild function in pandas or numpy for doing this

**EDIT**

Answers by @chris and @jazrael work for me. I am using @chris second solution as it is easy to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `df.index.groupby`:

```
df.index.groupby(df['1'])
#or
{k:list(v) for k,v in df.index.groupby(df['1']).items()}
```

Output:

```
{0.4217: [13],
 0.4784: [0, 5, 16],
 0.5173: [18],
 0.5294: [3],
 0.5397: [6],
 0.541: [15],
 0.5555: [4],
 0.5763: [8],
 0.5841: [19],
 0.618: [1],
 0.6273: [12],
 0.649: [17],
 0.6735: [2],
 0.7665: [11],
 0.8036: [10],
 0.8045: [9],
 0.8174: [7],
 0.8768: [14]}
```

Comment: <code> df.index.groupby(df[1]) </code> gives me <code>{0.4217: Int64Index([13], dtype='int64'), 0.4359: Int64Index([5], dtype='int64'), 0.4719: Int64Index([16], ........ so on}</code>

Comment: Please try the second line ;)

Comment: @Chris great answer. Mind to share what is the index for in df.index.groupby. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use dictionary comprehension for `Series` of index values in strings with `join` or in `list`s:

```
dfs = {x: df.rename(str).reset_index().groupby(x, sort=False)['index'].apply(', '.join) 
          for x in df.columns}
```

---

```
#select by column name
print (dfs['1'])
1
0.4784    0, 5, 16
0.6180           1
0.6735           2
0.5294           3
0.5555           4
0.5397           6
0.8174           7
0.5763           8
0.8045           9
0.8036          10
0.7665          11
0.6273          12
0.4217          13
0.8768          14
0.5410          15
0.6490          17
0.5173          18
0.5841          19
Name: index, dtype: object
```

If need lists:

```
dfs = {x: df.reset_index().groupby(x, sort=False)['index'].apply(list) for x in df.columns}

#select by column name
print (dfs['1'])
1
0.4784    [0, 5, 16]
0.6180           [1]
0.6735           [2]
0.5294           [3]
0.5555           [4]
0.5397           [6]
0.8174           [7]
0.5763           [8]
0.8045           [9]
0.8036          [10]
0.7665          [11]
0.6273          [12]
0.4217          [13]
0.8768          [14]
0.5410          [15]
0.6490          [17]
0.5173          [18]
0.5841          [19]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael , can you kindly explain what is happening in second soluiton of yours. Also any good source where I can learn about pandas ? thank-you

Comment: @WhySoSerious - My code loop each column in dictionary comprehension for strings or lists in Series.

Comment: @jezrael when I'm adding print(dfs['1']) i'm getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (dfs['1'])
KeyError: '1'

Comment: @jezrael I have loaded that data into excel and I'm Reading from there when I'm giving print (dfs) all columns list data is coming Name: index, dtype: object, 1: 1 ..upto 4 but when  I'm giving print (dfs['1']) it is throwing KeyError : '1'